# sql join query not working

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables with data
tab1.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
compid    |  user_id   |    compdate    |     description   |
------------------------------------------------------------
C0001     |  U000001   |   2012-02-29   |      desc1        |
C0002     |  U000002   |   2012-02-29   |      desc1        |
C0003     |  U000001   |   2012-03-01   |      desc1        |
C0004     |  U000003   |   2012-03-01   |      desc1        |
C0005     |  U000001   |   2012-03-02   |      desc1        |
C0006     |  U000008   |   2012-03-02   |      desc1        |
C0007     |  U000212   |   2012-03-02   |      desc1        |
C0008     |  U010222   |   2012-03-02   |      desc1        |
C0009     |  U000091   |   2012-03-02   |      desc1        |
C0010     |  U010222   |   2012-03-02   |      desc1        |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

tab2.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
compid    | assigned_to|    assignedon  |     status        |
------------------------------------------------------------
C0001     |  U000101   |   2012-02-29   |      Closed        |
C0002     |  U000101   |   2012-02-29   |      Open          |
C0003     |  U000102   |   2012-03-02   |      Closed        |
C0004     |  U000102   |   2012-03-02   |      Closed        |
C0005     |  U000101   |   2012-03-02   |      Open          |
C0006     |  U000101   |   2012-03-02   |      Closed        |
C0008     |  U000101   |   2012-03-02   |      Closed        |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now what I want is:
All the records whose `Status = 'Open'` and also the record from `tab1` whose entry is not in `tab2`.
The query should fetch records whose `compdate = '2012-03-02'`.

What I tried is:

```
select  
 from tab1 a 
      left join dbo.tab2 b 
      on a.CompId = b.CompId 
where b.StatusFlag = 'Open' 
  and a.CompDate = CONVERT(nvarchar(30),Dateadd(day,-1,getdate()),106)
```

Expected results :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 compid  |  user_id   |    compdate    |description  |assigned_to  | assignedon |status| 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 C0005   |  U000001   |   2012-03-02   |   desc1     | U000101     | 2012-03-02 | open |   
 C0009   |  U000001   |   2012-03-02   |   desc1     | Null        | NULL       | null |
 C0010   |  U000001   |   2012-03-02   |   desc1     | null        | null       | null |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you want records with status 'open' why are you using `!=`?

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you getting an error or just not the expected result?

Comment: It looks like you're selecting rows where the compdate is two days before the current date. If you want rows where the compdate is '2012-03-02', you'll have to wait till Sunday to run this.

Comment: @ CFL_Jeff : in the result i only get the record from whose status='Open' but no record whose entry is not made in tab2.

Comment: You want `( b.StatusFlag = 'Open' or b.StatusFlag is null )`

Comment: @kumarchaudhari: Probably adding an expected result based on your sample data would help understand what you want

Comment: @kumarchaudhari: Why is C0007 not being displayed in the result?

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho : C0007 shold also be displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select *
From 
   Tab1
Left Join
   Tab2
on 
   Tab1.CompID = Tab2.CompID
Where
   (Tab2.Status = 'open' or 
   Tab2.Status is null) and
   Tab1.CompDate = '2012-03-02'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to select?

```
select * from tab2 t2
left join tab1 t1 on t1.compid = t2.compid
where t2.[status] = 'Open' and
t1.compdate in ( select compdate from tab1 except
select assignedon from tab2) 
and t1.compdate = '20120302'
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're looking for a union of the data: All records with status is Open `union` records from tab1 not present in tab2. This would be that query:

```
select * from (
  select t1.compid, t1.user_id, t1.compdate from tab1 t1
  left join tab2 t2 on t1.compid = t2.compid
  where t2.compid is null
  union
  select compid, assigned_to, assignedon from tab2
  where statusflag = 'Open'
) t
where compdate = '2012-03-02'
```